# How to iterate over a numpy array at a given axis?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have an ndarray of shape, say

```
my_array = np.zeros((Na, Nb, Nc))
```

and I have Nb bunches of data of shape (Na, Nc)

I would like to fill "my_array" with my bunches of data as follows:

```
for b, bit in zip(range(Nb), my_bits):
    my_array[:, b, :] = bit
```

but I would like to do this for any arbitray axis for an arbitrary shape data set. How would I do this?

** EDIT **
Someone pointed out an ambiguity in my question. Below is an example code of what I know how to do, leading to what I don't know.

What I know:

```
my_bits = [np.ones((Na, Nc)) for j in range(Nb)]
my_array = np.zeros((Na, Nb, Nc))
for b, bit in zip(range(Nb), my_bits):
    my_array[:, b, :] = bit
```

Generically we could consider

```
my_array = np.zeros((N1, N2, ..., Nj, ..., Nmax))
bit = np.ones((N1, N2, ..., Nj-1, Nj+1, ..., Nmax))
my_bits = [bit]*Nj
```

From there I would like to fill my_array with my_bits along axis Nj. How would I do this? I am looking at the nditer function, but I am not sure what to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with dimensions here.
If I understood it correctly, `my_array[:, 0, :]` is same dimension as `my_bits`. So the assignment should be done like this:

```
import numpy as np

Na = 2
Nb = 2
Nc = 2
my_array = np.zeros((Na, Nb, Nc))

my_bits = np.ones((Na, Nc))

print('my_array before', my_array)

for b in range(Nb):
  my_array[:, b, :] = my_bits

print('my_array after', my_array)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out an ambiguity in my question. I'll fix it as soon as I am done with this comment. my_bits is a list (tuple, array, anything iterable) of data bits of dimension (Na, Nc).

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want [numpy.transpose](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html)

```py
list_of_2d_arrays = [ make_2d_array() for i in range(Nb) ]  # each has shape=(Na,Nc)
tensor3d = np.array(list_of_2d_arrays) # shape = (Nb,Na,Nc)
# now shift the dimensions around
X = np.transpose(tensor3d,(1,0,2)) # has shape (Na,Nb,Nc)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `transpose` to move the iteration axis to a known position, front or last, is done in some `numpy` functions.

Another approach is to construct a `slice` object, and iterate that.

```
In [46]: arr = np.zeros((2,3,4),int)
In [47]: idx = np.full((arr.ndim,), slice(None))
In [48]: n=2
In [49]: for i in range(arr.shape[n]):
    ...:     idx[n] = i
    ...:     arr[tuple(idx)] = i+1
    ...:     
In [50]: arr
Out[50]: 
array([[[1, 2, 3, 4],
        [1, 2, 3, 4],
        [1, 2, 3, 4]],

       [[1, 2, 3, 4],
        [1, 2, 3, 4],
        [1, 2, 3, 4]]])
```

for another axis

```
In [56]: arr = np.zeros((2,3,4),int)
In [57]: idx = np.full((arr.ndim,), slice(None))
In [58]: n=1
In [59]: for i in range(arr.shape[n]):
    ...:     idx[n] = i
    ...:     arr[tuple(idx)] = i+1
    ...:     
In [60]: arr
Out[60]: 
array([[[1, 1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2, 2],
        [3, 3, 3, 3]],

       [[1, 1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2, 2],
        [3, 3, 3, 3]]])
```

In this case `idx` varies as:

```
[slice(None, None, None) 0 slice(None, None, None)]
[slice(None, None, None) 1 slice(None, None, None)]
[slice(None, None, None) 2 slice(None, None, None)]
```

The key is that an indexing expression has a tuple equivalent, which can be constructed programatically:

```
In [61]: np.s_[:,3,:]
Out[61]: (slice(None, None, None), 3, slice(None, None, None))
```